# Changing the order of the Cartesian Product defines an homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, direct-product

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. The function $f:G\times H \to H\times G$ with $f(g,h) = (h,g)$ defines an homomorphism?

I think it does, because if $(g_1,h_1),(g_2,h_2) \in G \times H$, we have:
$$f((g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)) = f((g_1g_2,h_1h_2))=(h_1h_2,g_1g_2) = (h_1,g_1)(h_2,g_2) = f(g_1,h_1)f(g_2,h_2)$$
But is my thought right? Thanks.

Comment: "But is my thought right?" Please let us know, where you have doubts. Only then we can help you, so that you can become sure of your thoughts. As it stands, the next one will simply comment" YES, well done!", and this doesn't really help. Then you'll have to ask each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine. Well done!

You can improve it by using the $\rm\LaTeX$ `align` command.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot!